# What user's rights are used when a client gets a file from an SFTP server?

Tags: ssh, security, sftp

When a client connects to an SFTP server to get a file, is the file normally read from the host system using the rights granted to the account running the SFTP client or using the rights granted to the account running the SFTP server?

If it's the former then the client determines the files available, which makes a lot of sense to me but if its the later then the server must have access to all the files to be served and any client can get every file.

I'd try it out but I don't have access to the flavour of SFTP in question ([Control-M Managed File Transfer](https://www.bmc.com/it-solutions/control-m-managed-file-transfer.html) service), the vendor of which is telling me its the later in their case.

This is more about how a well-behaved SFTP server should work than about the details of any particular implementation.

Answer (score 4):

> is the file normally read from the host system using the rights granted to the account running the SFTP client or using the rights granted to the account running the SFTP server?

It's never the former. Sometimes the latter, but typically it's *neither.*

The SFTP server has no knowledge about the client's environment at all. The only things it knows about you are the credentials you supply – the username is mapped to an account on the SFTP server's side, and that account somehow determines your rights.

In most cases, SFTP servers are built to use **system** accounts on the target machine, as SFTP is actually a subprotocol of SSH (not to be confused with FTPS, which isn't) and many SFTP server implementations are fully-featured SSH servers.

So although the typical SFTP (SSH) server initially runs as a highly privileged account, it uses your provided username to *switch its process to the corresponding OS account* and from that point onwards, the connection only has the privileges that the specified account on the server would normally have, with the server's OS kernel enforcing access checks.

(For example, the OpenSSH `sshd` initially runs as root, but as soon as you authenticate as "pat", you're talking to an SFTP server process that runs under the 'pat' account.)

> the server must have access to all the files to be served and any client can get every file.

But if you're dealing with a special-purpose SFTP server that runs under a normal OS account and verifies user credentials against its internal account database (i.e. "virtual accounts"), this still *does not imply* that all SFTP clients have the same rights.

It only means that the *maximum* possible rights of any client are no higher than that of the account running the SFTP server – however, the SFTP server itself can enforce additional restrictions on top of that. After all, client commands are still processed by the SFTP server's code first – they don't go directly to the server's OS – so it can still perfectly well apply different rules to individual clients.

(For example, in FileZilla Server – which serves FTP/FTPS, not SFTP, but the concepts are still the same – the actual server process performs all file operations as a single account and uses virtual FTP accounts that have no relationship to OS accounts, but it still allows configuring which paths each account may or may not access and what operations are allowed.)

So in your specific example, it seems that the Control-M File Transfer server can work both ways: it can either use Windows accounts directly (and I assume switch to their privileges at OS level), or it can use internal accounts (applying restrictions through its own code). But in all cases it is based on explicitly provided login details, never implicitly on the client-side account.